# Forward touch events of UIScrollView to parent view by not blocking the UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I have multiple `UIViews` in a `UIViewController` and every `UIView` has `UIScrollViews`. I have to move `UIViews` horizontal by touch events. `UIScrollViews` should scroll only vertical. But `UIScrollViews` are swallowing touch events and so `UIView` is not moving. I made a custom `UIScrollView` class to forward touch events like below, but on that way `UIScrollView` doesn't scroll.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIView *result = nil;
    for (UIView *child in self.subviews)
        if ([child pointInside:point withEvent:event])
            if ((result = [child hitTest:point withEvent:event]) != nil)
                break;

    return result;
}
```

How can I pass touches from `UIScrollView` to it's parent view by also making `UIScrollView` work?

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you put your views with scrollviews to big scrollview with only horisontal scrolling enabled? I tried it once, works for me

Comment: These UIViews are stacked views and I have to move the next one on the previous one, not like scrolling all.

Comment: You need exaccly move the next one on the previous one or you just need them to behave like book? You can use scrollview with pagging enabled

Comment: I exactly need to move next view on previous view. Previous view shouldn't move. Not like book or scrollview.